# Getting Application Configuration in doWithSpring Colsure of Plugin Descriptor

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am extending the Spring oauth Plugin and want to declare beans for some Classes I extended like the *[OAuthConfig](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/model/OAuthConfig.java)* class, I want to declare the extended class as a bean in the doWithSpring closure of the plugin Descriptor

```
public class MyOAuthConfig extends org.scribe.model.OAuthConfig {


   public MyOAuthConfig(String key, String secret) {
    super(key, secret); 
   }

}
```

I want to declare this class as a plugin bean

```
doWithSpring{
   passportOAuthConfig(com.mycompany.security.MyOAuthConfig){
        key = [application configuration here]
   }
}
```

How can I get a grails application configuration here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have access to `application` which is the `grailsApplication` from `doWithSpring`. So you can do the following:

```
doWithSpring = {
  ...
   passportOAuthConfig(com.mycompany.security.MyOAuthConfig){
        key = application.config.someValueFromHere
   }
  ...
}
```